# Error when resizing a ext4 partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, resize

I used Gparted to resize a ext4 partition but it fails. 
This is the command:

```
% resize2fs -p /dev/sdb5
```

> resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
>
> resize2fs: Filesystem has unsupported read-only feature(s) while trying to open /dev/sdb5 Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

I've been searching about this problem and I found similar issues in CentOS and Redhat for which it is recommended to use resize4fs (ext4). However this is not available for Ubuntu 16.04.

How could I tackle this problem?

Comment: Partition has to be unmounted. You cannot run from your working system, but need to use live installer's gparted or download the latest gparted ISO and use it.

Comment: Using gparted from a recent live CD is the best answer I can think of too.  Can you post it as an answer?  I would, but I don't want to take credit from you.

Comment: There is no `resize4fs`.  It appears that you are using a newer ext4 feature in which case, you need to use a newer release than 16.04 to resize it.

Comment: Are you root/did you use sudo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments a recent gparted live CD solved my problem. I could resize the partition without problems using a live CD of gparted v0.30.0.

However my laptop did not boot after the resizing. The grub got destroyed!! 
I solved this with a live CD of [systemrescueCd](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/Download/). I restored the grub using the solution 2 from [here](http://www.system-rescue-cd.org/disk-partitioning/Repairing-a-damaged-Grub/).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same error because the partition was not mounted.

After creating a mount point and then mounting, `resize2fs` completed without error.

```
mkdir /temp-mount-point
mount /dev/sdb5 /temp-mount-point
resize2fs /dev/sdb5
```

> resize2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
>   Filesystem at /dev/sdb5 is mounted on /temp-mount-point; on-line resizing required
>   old_desc_blocks = 1, new_desc_blocks = 699
>   The filesystem on /dev/sdb5 is now 1463818240 (4k) blocks long.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked of me:

- Download and build the latest version of [e2fsprogs](https://sourceforge.net/projects/e2fsprogs/).
- Replace the existing `/usr/sbin/e2fsck` and `/usr/sbin/resize2fs` - after making a backup of course.

This also eliminated the infamous "update e2fsck" issue as well.